# Saddle or frame shape for painful Coccyx?

Tags: frames, saddle

As a child I was very active, and in a weight-lifting injury I damaged my Coccyx, making it very difficult to sit in the same position for long periods of time. As such, bicycling, what once was a staple joy in my life, has become painful. Is there a seat or frame design that takes pressure off the tail bone so that I can ride pain-free once again?

Comment: Since you ask about frame designs, you could also look into recumbents. Riding a recumbent is a more familiar sitting position than a traditional bicycle.

Comment: Moved. Like I said though, I really don't have any experience, and don't know whether it would fix your specific problem.  So it might be helpful to wait around for a bit to see if you get some  better suggestions.

Comment: It's bizarre, but it is specifically leaning back that hurts. For instance, sitting in my office chair I have to frequently lean forward, over my desk to relieve the pain. Yet, when I've ridden bicycles--many of which have a similar riding position that I describe--my Coccyx feels like it's on fire. I have to stop after 5 minutes. Could it just be a matter of adjusting the bike to fit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good seat should put most of the pressure sitz bones rather than the tail bone. You'll probably want to look for something like the [Rido Saddle](http://www.rido-cyclesaddles.com/) which has the back cut out and would probably minimize pressure on your coccyx. I can't say whether this type of saddle would work well for you, but in my mind it seems like it might do a good job.

Comment: Thank you! Specifically, I found [this](http://www.rido-cyclesaddles.com/who-will-benefit-c100106.html) saddle to be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

you could check some of the [Specialized Body Geometry saddles](http://www.specialized.com/specs/spec.jsp?speccode=bodygeometrysaddles).

They also feature the back cut out design as recommended by Kibbee, hopefully that should take some pressure off the tail bone.

Also as they come in 3 different widths, you can choose the size that fits you best. The recommended width is determined based on the distance between the sit bones and the ridding position.

Comment: Interesting! That one also seems more likely to be testable in the shop, since it's from Spec.